# How to downgrade between General Availability versions of MySQL?

Tags: mysql

There are some things that are not compatible with .NET framework for MySQL version 8.0.29.

Now i want to downgrade to MySQL version 8.0.28 but unable to find the process to do so.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Did you try installing 8.0.28 over 8.0.29?  If so, did you get any useful error messages?  Try that on a separate copy of your data.  While I don't think it will "break", it is risky.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in uncharted territory.

As the link in the comment above says, MySQL doesn't support downgrades. That is, they don't test it, they don't guarantee it, and they don't document a process for it. This is probably a business decision on their part, not a technical reality. It *might* technically work, but they have decided not to offer any resources to help.

One problem is that in the MySQL 8.0 era, they are more likely to implement changes that are not backward-compatible between minor releases. This means the tablespace files you have in 8.0.29 might not be readable by some earlier version.

You can try reading the downgrade notes for MySQL 5.7 to get a feel for some of the things you need to keep in mind: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/downgrading.html and its child pages.

The safer path to downgrade is to use `mysqldump` or `mysqlpump` to export a logical backup of your data, then import that data to a different MySQL Server version. This is much slower, but it avoids backward-compatibility changes with respect to physical tablespace format.

You might still run into logical compatibility issues, for example if you had used a data type or a function that doesn't exist in the earlier version.

By the way, I am not a .NET user, so I haven't tested this, but based on reading the Release Notes, I guess you might have to downgrade to a version older than 8.0.28. See my answer to https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/312926/2703

This situation is clearly not ideal. You need to do some careful testing and possibly export and import dump files to multiple versions of MySQL Server. It's going to be time-consuming.

The issue of .NET getting errors related to utf8mb3 has been reported here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107259

I suggest you should make an account on the MySQL bugs site and click the "Affects Me" button for the above bug. The more people who do that, the more they prioritize working on fixing it.